# unity webgl not working on server

Tags: webgl

I own the servers of hokuco.com, I am wondering why my test build(not a development build) is not working in webgl I tried a test run as a .exe and it works fine. here is the url to my webgl project, can you determine what is wrong?
http://hokuco.com/test/index.html
(no files on my server are blocked, feel free to view the .htacess, js and other files) the screen is black and nothing is happening.
.htacess:

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteRule (.*)Release(.*)\.js $1Compressed$2\.jsgz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Release(.*)\.data $1Compressed$2\.datagz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Release(.*)\.mem $1Compressed$2\.memgz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Release(.*)\.unity3d $1Compressed$2\.unity3dgz [L]
AddEncoding gzip .jsgz
AddEncoding gzip .datagz
AddEncoding gzip .memgz
AddEncoding gzip .unity3dgz
```

all my js files seem to be blocked.(but not jsgz...)

Comment: it works fine in localhost

Comment: I get 404 for the Release files. For example this one: (http://hokuco.com/test/Release/UnityConfig.js). The server does not seem to be hosting it. Did you upload the Release folder? Where did you put it?

Comment: in filezilla everything is there...

Comment: hmmmm it seems as if javascript is blocked

Comment: is it a prob with my .htacess?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just simply delete the .htacess file